# Is it okay to use people's Creative Commons licensed flickr photos?

Tags: creative-commons

I need some photos of people for a design, is it acceptable to use Creative Commons licensed photos from sites like flickr of real people? Or is it not acceptable because they didn’t agree, even though they licensed the photos under CC?